# Dividir una cadena de texto

Tags: javascript, html, nodejs, input

Me gustaría dividir el siguiente mensaje de salida, es de un input tipo week que me da por ejemplo "2021 W19".

Me gustaría guardar en una variable el año y en otra la semana.
Para así poder manejar su salida dependiendo de la fecha que quiera el usuario.

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Os dejo una imagen de la salida del mensaje del input week:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y aquí es donde quiero dividirlos, por un lado tener el año y por otro la semana.
Gracias.

Comment: `const a = str.split("-"); // ["2021", "W19"]` [Referencia](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Comment: ```let [año, semana] = "2021-W19".split('-');``` eso quieres? bueno puedes ocupar la función split para dividir una cadena por medio de un divisor.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, me ha servido el de Victor, era más fácil de lo que estaba intentando hacer, y que mi manejo con split no es muy bueno. Mil gracias!

Comment: Por favor, no usen los comentarios para responder la pregunta. Lean [comentar en todas partes](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El patrón que tenes en todas las weeks es el guión '-' que te separa los dos datos que te interesan

Podes usar la función split, que a partir de un string y un delimitador te genera un arreglo de strings. https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

```js
const nodeWeek = "2012-W19"
const array = nodeWeek.split('-')
const año = array[0]
const semana = array[1]
console.log(año, semana)
```

O de una forma más legible utilizando desestructuración de un arreglo https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

```js
const nodeWeek = "2012-W19"
const [año, semana] = nodeWeek.split('-')
console.log(año, semana)
```